# Szemeredi Trotter and additive combinatorics on A+AA

Tags: combinatorics, combinatorial-geometry, extremal-combinatorics, additive-combinatorics

I am trying to get a lower bound on $|A+AA|$ where $A$ is a set, and $A+AA=\{a+bc: a,b,c \in A\}$ using Szemeredi Trotter.

I would think we need to form lines of the form $y=ax+b$ where $a,b \in A$, but I'm not sure what to let be the "points" in this situation so that we can apply the inequality: $I(P,L) \leq (PL)^{2/3}+P+L$.

Thank you!

Comment: Thank you, but I meant a lower bound in terms of $|A|$ (where we  assume $A$ is a subset of the positive real numbers).

Comment: What's $I(P,L)$?

Comment: The incidences of a point in $P$ and a line in $L$. I.e. $I(P,L)=\{(p,l)\in P \times L: p \in l\}$.

Comment: What if $|A|$ where $\geq \infty$.  Then is the lower bound function (in terms of $|A|$) supposed to have some meaning there as well?

Comment: I am being a bit messy by not including cardinality signs, but I hope the statement is clear.

Comment: No, you're right, I wanted to assume that it is a finite subset. Thank you!

Comment: I think I got it:

Comment: So we have $|A|^2$ lines of the form above. 
Let the point set be ${(d,ac+b):a,b,c,d \in A}$. This has cardinality at most $|A||A+AA|$. 

So we have that our RHS is $\leq (|A|^2|A||A+AA|)^{2/3}$. How many incidences do we get? $|A|^3$ (i.e. d=c). Thus we have $|A|^3 \leq  (|A|^2|A||A+AA|)^{2/3}$ which gives $|A| \leq |A+AA|^2/3$ or $|A|^{3/2} \leq |A+AA|$