# Bounding $|A+BC|$ for sets of real numbers

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

> Let $A,B,C \subset \Bbb R$. I want to prove that the number of elements of the form $a+bc$, denoted $|A+BC|$, is at least $c \sqrt{|A||B||C|}$ for some global constant $c$.

For that, we consider the set $P$ of all points in the plane of the form $(c_1, a+bc)$ and the set $L$ of all lines of the form $y=a+bx$.

A theorem says that the number of pairs $(l,p)$ of a line $l$ and a point $p\in l$ is at most a constant $c_1$ times $(|P||L|)^{2/3}+|P|+|L|$.

Now $|P|=|C||A+BC|, \; |L|=|A||B|$, and each of the lines in $L$ has exactly $|C|$ points on it, so the number of pairs $\{p \in l\}$ is $|A||B||C|$.

Thus by the theorem:

$$|A||B||C| \leq c_1(|A|^{2/3}|B|^{2/3}|C|^{2/3}|A+BC|^{2/3}+|C||A+BC|+|A||B|)$$

Now, it is clear what we want to do from here: if the first term in the RHS is dominant, then the inequality

$$|A||B||C| \leq c_2(|A|^{2/3}|B|^{2/3}|C|^{2/3}|A+BC|^{2/3})$$

proves the required result bny rearranging.

the third term is indeed negligible $|A||B| \leq |A|^{2/3}|B|^{2/3}|C|^{2/3}|A+BC|^{2/3}$ because it is equivalent to $|A||B| \leq |C|^2|A+BC|^2$ which is easily true since $|A| \leq |A+BC|$ and $|B| \leq |A+BC|$.

So we are left with showing $|C||A+BC| \leq c_3(|A||B||C||A+BC|)^{2/3}$
for some constant $c_3$, or equivalently

$|C||A+BC| \leq c_3 |A|^2|B|^2$

But **this does not hold**, even if we assume $|B| \leq |C|$ or vice versa (by exchanging $B$ and $C$ everywhere), because even for $|A|=1, B=C$ we don't have $|B||BB| \leq c_3 |B|^2$.

> How can I fix the proof?

This is a generalization of [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/827562/szemeredi-trotter-and-additive-combinatorics-on-aaa) that asked the particular case $A=B=C$, in which the above method works.

Comment: Can you please link to the theorem you used initially?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Szemer%C3%A9di%E2%80%93Trotter_theorem?wprov=sfla1